# jQuery / Twitter Bootstrap data-loading-text button with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this exact example working on my website:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

However, simply including this HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Loading state</button>
```

Does not work. I'm running jQuery 1.7.x and have loaded the Bootstrap JS files.

To be specific: I want the button to move to the "loading" text change for a slight delay, then go back to the regular text. There doesn't seem to be a good example available online from my Googling (most are asking for a permanent state change or toggle), and the Bootstrap site itself is lacking in documentation here.

Comment: Is not that bootstrap lacks any doc, it's up to you to implement your desired logic :)) [e.g. to set the button loading when you fire an event, then to put it back to normal state when task is done].

Comment: I would argue that if you show someone an example of something and include incomplete code for the example, that this is indeed poor documentation.

Comment: BS is a _presentation_ tool, so it should not include much business stuff. Anyway it was included in the repo as user below pointed out, so keep it up with your work!

Comment: "BS is a presentation tool, so it should not include much business stuff." What does that even mean? That isn't an excuse for not documenting code right next to the specific example they provide with incomplete code (HTML only).

Comment: It's not just html, scroll down doc till `$().button('loading')` for example - then it's up to you when and how to set a button's state. The "slight delay" [i.e. `setTimeout()`]is very basic js, and so beyond Bootstrap's scope.

Comment: @moonwave99 1) None of that JS you mention is documented on this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons  2) This is not business logic, this is UI.  Unless you work for a company that manufactures shirt buttons, button is not a business object.  3) I completely agree that such an example should show the javascript, so that it is clear where the line is drawn between behavior provided by bootstrap and behavior you implement.  Bootstrap does provide behavior.  I.e. you specify data attributes that point a button to a modal, and bootstrap will open the modal: behavior!

Comment: @AaronLS [are you sure](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/22/43990136.jpg/)? And by the way, the accepted answer points to the script behind *example page itself* - I think that instead of complaining against a nice [and free] tool, a bit of digging would have solved the problem, even if the doc was pretty clear at least to me. Still feeling it unclear? Provide a pull req with an explicit example, community would have been glad :))

Comment: @moonwave99 Sure, where is the repo for the jquery documentation site?

Comment: @AaronLS [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/javascript.html).

Comment: The bootstrap documentation is poorly organized on this point. I just went through the same thing: thinking that all you have to do is add data-loading-text to an element for it to be applied (because that's what the docs say before moving on to the next example, http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) The part about .button('loading') should appear next to where it's used, not several screens down.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In the documentation page, there is a file being loaded called application.js. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js

```
// button state demo
$('#fat-btn')
    .click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset')
        }, 3000)
    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for hunting it down. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes. :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. Some examples aren't that well documented.

Comment: This is so freaking annoying!!

Comment: Isn't this cheating on their part?

Comment: This helped me, but as it turns out it looks like the current (3.1.0) bootstrap.min.js includes application.js. I think what really fixed my problem was going from an inline click handler (<button onclick="dosomething()"/>) to a JQuery click handler attach as shown in the example.

Answer (score 21):

Or just add this so it picks up the Twitter Bootstrap attribute.

```
$('button[data-loading-text]').click(function () {
    $(this).button('loading');
});
```

Comment: This worked well for me. If you also want to bind to dynamicly added buttons: $(document).on('click', 'button[data-loading-text]', function () {
        $(this).button('loading');
    });

Answer (score 6):

Make a note of how the accepted answer converted the jQuery button object to a js var before running button('loading') on it because, while this works, button('loading') will not work when used directly on the jQuery button object.

Answer (score 2):

just include the bootstrap library:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js "></script>
```

This is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bootstrap Example</TITLE>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css ">
<STYLE>
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnD" data-loading-text="=)">hola!!!</button>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btnD').click(function(){
                  var btn = $(this); 
                  btn.button('loading');
            });
        });
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question.  OP says that they already are loading the bootstrap lib along with jquery.  Do you have any other suggestions for solving the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

also, jquery has .delay() method which may be easier to work with than setTimeout.

Comment: for future answers, you get better rating if you provide solid example of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

My Button

```
<button type="submit" id="upgrade-subscription" class="btn btn-primary btn-subscribe" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Payment Processing">upgrade</button>
```

JQ

```
$('#upgrade-subscription').click(function () {
    $(this).button('loading');
});
```

Comment: Hey @Manoj, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add an explanation of what you did or why it works?

Comment: I added this to prevent many click on payment button
Show loader and disable button

Answer (score -7):

just put a small js

```
onclick="$(this).button('loading');"
```

Comment: This kind of inline event declaration is considered as a bad practice. You should instead use pure JS event listeners.