# Bootstrap data-loading-text not delaying when clicked in Opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, opencart2.x

First I followed the replies of a similar topic:
[jQuery / Twitter Bootstrap data-loading-text button with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118202/jquery-twitter-bootstrap-data-loading-text-button-with-delay))

But they didn't work for me.

I already have the code below inserted in my website:
http://tecidosecortinas.com.br/cetim-de-festa-3-metros-de-largura-vermelho

```
$('#simular')
    .click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset')
        }, 9000)
    });
```

Click on the green button (Calcular).
It loads the loading text for one or two seconds.
I need the delay to be higher.

Comment: You code looks correct! I think there is something else trigger the `btn.button('reset')`, like ajax complete !

Comment: your website is not work.

Comment: thanks for your help @IsmailRBOUH. I don't have any knowledge about javascript. So I'm hostage of it.

Comment: @HarnishDesign the website is loading correctly.

Comment: @ViniciusMendonça Maybe, it is working in your side. but, It is not working for me. You can check this screenshot. https://s31.postimg.org/lev8ocig9/screnshote.jpg Maybe, maybe, Your domain have block for other IP.

Comment: I'm sorry @HarnishDesign, it was an issue with .htaccess . Thanks for reporting that! Now it's working, try again.

Comment: @ViniciusMendonça Issue is still.

Comment: That's weird. Now I have normal access even from a different country of mine. Where are you located?